# Web.Optimizations - any way to get all includes from a Style/Script Bundle?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

I'm working with some dynamic bundling which adds CSS and JS files based on configuration.

I spin up a new StyleBundle such that:

```
var cssBundle = new StyleBundle("~/bundle/css");
```

Then loop through config and add any found includes:

```
cssBundle.Include(config.Source);
```

Following the loop I want to check if there was actually any files/directories included. I know there's EnumerateFiles() but I don't think this 100% serves the purpose.

Anyone else done anything similar previously?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Bundle` class uses an internal items list that is not exposed to the application<strike>, and isn't necessarily accessible via reflection (I tried and couldn't get any contents)</strike>.  You can fetch some information about this using the `BundleResolver` class like so:

```
var cssBundle = new StyleBundle("~/bundle/css");
cssBundle.Include(config.Source);

// if your bundle is already in BundleTable.Bundles list, use that.  Otherwise...
var collection = new BundleCollection();
collection.Add(cssBundle)

// get bundle contents
var resolver = new BundleResolver(collection);
List<string> cont = resolver.GetBundleContents("~/bundle/css").ToList();
```

If you just need a count then:

```
int count = resolver.GetBundleContents("~/bundle/css").Count();
```

**Edit: using reflection**

Apparently I did something wrong with my reflection test before.

This actually works:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Optimization;

...

int count = ((ItemRegistry)typeof(Bundle).GetProperty("Items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(cssBundle, null)).Count;
```

You should probably add some safety checks there of course, and like a lot of reflection examples this violates the intended safety of the `Items` property, but it *does* work.

Comment: Thanks Corey that looks good, only issue I have is that the bundle is getting added to the collection in order for it's contents being counted. Ideally I would like to check contents to ensure there's > 0 BEFORE adding to collection. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can use the reflection example to get the count, or create a new (and temporary) collection as I did in the initial code sample above and use the `BundleResolver` to get the list of included files.  The bundle doesn't become available to the rest of the system until you add it to the `BundleTable.Bundles` collection, so you can use either method to check the bundle before making it generally available.

Comment: Isn't ItemRegistry internal though?

Comment: What about this instead? 

`var itemCount = ((IList)(typeof(Bundle)).GetProperty("Items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(bundleCollection.First(), null)).Count;`

Comment: The `ItemRegistry` type is exposed, just the instance contained in the `Bundle` class isn't.  But yes, casting to `IList` seems to be suitable too.  I have a tendency to cast to the most concrete type where possible... it's a failing of mine :)

Comment: For some reason I'm getting compile time error trying to reference ItemRegistry but never mind. Works with IList but agree concrete type would be best. Marked as answer thank you Corey :)

Comment: @Corey, the `GetBundleContents()` does not return missing files, so going to back to the TS' question "I want to check if there was ACTUALLY any files/directories included", this does not seem to be a solution.

Comment: @HermanKan Are you trying to get the list that was configured or the list that is sent to the client on request?

Comment: @Corey, I mean the former, assuming that if a file is added to a bundle, there must be a reason for doing that, so the file is expected to be in the bundle. This does not apply to path wildcards though, where the exact quantity is usually not an issue.

Comment: @HermanKan the reflection method should give you the list that was created, but from there you'll have to do some file enumeration code to get the actual list of files.

Comment: @Corey, I have posted below a completely different approach that does not require bundles to have been included to the collection for their files to get enumerable.

Comment: In addition, GetBundleContents() method will read files, apply transforms, and cache the result. If you add bundle transform later, the newly added transform won't be applied because cached content is availabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following extension methods for `Bundle`:

```
public static class BundleHelper
{
    private static Dictionary<Bundle, List<string>> bundleIncludes = new Dictionary<Bundle, List<string>>();
    private static Dictionary<Bundle, List<string>> bundleFiles = new Dictionary<Bundle, List<string>>();

    private static void EnumerateFiles(Bundle bundle, string virtualPath)
    {
        if (bundleIncludes.ContainsKey(bundle))
            bundleIncludes[bundle].Add(virtualPath);
        else
            bundleIncludes.Add(bundle, new List<string> { virtualPath });

        int i = virtualPath.LastIndexOf('/');
        string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(virtualPath.Substring(0, i));

        if (Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            string fileName = virtualPath.Substring(i + 1);
            IEnumerable<string> fileList;

            if (fileName.Contains("{version}"))
            {
                var re = new Regex(fileName.Replace(".", @"\.").Replace("{version}", @"(\d+(?:\.\d+){1,3})"));
                fileName = fileName.Replace("{version}", "*");
                fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, fileName).Where(file => re.IsMatch(file));
            }
            else // fileName may contain '*'
                fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, fileName);

            if (bundleFiles.ContainsKey(bundle))
                bundleFiles[bundle].AddRange(fileList);
            else
                bundleFiles.Add(bundle, fileList.ToList());
        }
    }

    public static Bundle Add(this Bundle bundle, params string[] virtualPaths)
    {
        foreach (string virtualPath in virtualPaths)
            EnumerateFiles(bundle, virtualPath);

        return bundle.Include(virtualPaths);
    }

    public static Bundle Add(this Bundle bundle, string virtualPath, params IItemTransform[] transforms)
    {
        EnumerateFiles(bundle, virtualPath);
        return bundle.Include(virtualPath, transforms);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateIncludes(this Bundle bundle)
    {
        return bundleIncludes[bundle];
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(this Bundle bundle)
    {
        return bundleFiles[bundle];
    }
}
```

Then simply replace your `Include()` calls with `Add()`:

```
var bundle = new ScriptBundle("~/test")
    .Add("~/Scripts/jquery/jquery-{version}.js")
    .Add("~/Scripts/lib*")
    .Add("~/Scripts/model.js")
    );

var includes = bundle.EnumerateIncludes();
var files = bundle.EnumerateFiles();
```

If you are also using `IncludeDirectory()`, just complete the example by adding a respective `AddDirectory()` extension method.

Comment: An 'EnumerateFiles' method is actually built into the Bundle class.  It will return a list of BundleFile objects, which gives you access to not only each file's path, but also each file's IItemTransform(s), if any, that are applied.